# Failed to insert after implode an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I want to insert an imploded array to database..

Example: `$array = array('A','B','C')`.. after the implode, the value will be `A,B,C`, because I use `implode(",",$array)`...

Then I want to insert to database but failed, it said:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') values ('Operation Director','Operation Director','F001')

What should I do?

This is the MySQL query:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$position = $_POST['check'];
$checkok = implode(",",$position);

mysql_query("insert into checklist (check_ok,check_pos,check_code) values ('$checkok','$checkok','$code')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: can we see the rest of the query ?

Comment: table structure and your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unwanted comma in the query `checklist (check_ok,check_pos,check_code,)`. Remove it and try with,

```
mysql_query("insert into checklist (check_ok,check_pos,check_code) values ('$checkok','$checkok','$code')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: yeah,, i did not see it..sorry .. it worked now..

Comment: @haruya Note that you must escape your variables properly, especially since they come from `$_POST`. The answer given here is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and use **prepared statements** instead to protect against potential SQL injection attacks.

Secondly, you have a syntax error in the statement itself; the trailing comma before the first closing parenthesis.

Assuming you have configured the correct character set you could use this:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "insert into checklist (check_ok,check_pos,check_code) values ('%s','%s','%s')", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($checkok), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($checkok), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($code)
);

mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra comma from your query,

```
("insert into checklist (check_ok,check_pos,check_code,) values ('$checkok','$checkok','$code')"
                                                      ^
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding slashes/escaping just to be safe.

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
$position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['check']);
$checkok = implode(",",$position);
$checkok = mysql_real_escape_string($checkok);
$ret = mysql_query("INSERT INTO checklist (check_ok, check_pos, check_code)
                    VALUES ('$checkok','$checkok','$code')");
```